# How to read values of a JavaScript object returned as a sorted list from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp, dom

I get a sorted list from my controller to jsp page. I want to process this in javascript.

```
var foo = '${entityTypes}';
```

When I tried to loop this using a for in and read the values. but, it reads each and every character of the strings available. I tried json parse and stringify too, but still I get the same result.

```
var foo = '${entityTypes}';
alert(foo);

var str = JSON.stringify(foo);
var obj1 = JSON.parse(str); 
alert(obj1);    

for (var k in obj1) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        alert("Key is " + k + ", value is " + obj1[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the list? the value of `foo` is a String if you loop a string you get each of the chars

Comment: that makes sense. List is what I have assigned to foo. it's '${entityTypes}'. I guess I can convert this string to array using delimiter. Thanks for waking me up :)

Comment: Entitytypes is the list I get from back end controller to my jsp page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this done. I found it is a string by the comment of VeXii. Thanks Vexxi. As it's a string I used substr to remove unwanted characters.

```
    str = foo.substr(0, foo.length-1);
obj = str.substr(1);
```

this removed first and the last character. That means the square bracket open and close.

Then I used split method to get the string I wanted. Still I had an issue as my string came with a colon as the last character. Again I removed the colon using spring methods available.

```
var arr = obj.split(',');
```

Thanks for your comments. That helped me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

As the Java-List is not automatically converted into JSON-format, the value of `foo` is `entityList.toString()`. What you have to do is, to convert the Java-List by yourself into JSON-format.
But it is much cheaper to convert the `entityList` in the controller. [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for example are some nice Java libraries which do Entity-to-JSON-conversion.

Comment: entityList is not a javascript object to use toString. thanks for the suggestion. I get some ideas.